# How to subtract a total from the closest multiple of 10

Tags: python

So lets say I added some numbers and the total was 75. I then want to subtract 75 from the closest/highest multiple of 10 which would be 80 in this example.
Finally I want to output the answer after subtracting. I know that I can do it this way (below) but that would take forever if the range was bigger:

```
if total<80 and total>70:
subt=int(80-total)
    print(subt)
```

What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Try using a modulo. ie. 70%10 = 7. (7+1)*10 = 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
subt = (10-total%10)%10
```

Comment: The trailing `%10` isn't necessary. The difference is already guaranteed to be between 0 and 10.

Comment: @chepner consider total==10, in this case subt=10 without trailing modulo and 0 with it. I'm not sure what variant is requested by topic requestor.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be the modulo operator.

```
input = 75
print (10 - input % 10)
```